# Can I use ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork() within VpnService to send traffic through specific network (Mobile/WiFi)?

Tags: android, networking, vpn

I am trying to create a VpnService that will route all network traffic through specific network. For example use wifi network for streaming app and mobile network for mobile operator specific apps.

usinng ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork() method I am able send my apps traffic via specific network. I wonder If I can use same method within vpn service to route all apps traffic via specific network.

Comment: Can you update the apps themselves or are you looking for something that requires no updates to the apps themselves?

Comment: @Always Learning basically I want to control the network interface, a app should use. E.g. if request comes from streaming app it should be routed via wifi network and if request comes from chrome browser it should be routed via mobile network.